# How could I make this code more effective?

Tags: java

I want to figure out a more effective way to create this program. Instead of **if-else statements**, could it be possible to use some other form of loop or statement?

Here is the code:

```
class apples {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte x, y;
    x = 15;
    y = 28;

    boolean state = (true || false);

    if (x == y) {
        System.out.println(state);
    } else if (x > y) {
        System.out.println(state);
    } else if (x < y) {
        System.out.println(state);
    } else {
        System.out.println(state);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your code, and see what is different in all the if-else code blocks? All of them do the same task. Also, `true || false` is same as `true`.

Comment: You have have an unconditional `else` than can *never* happen.

Comment: The whole `main` method could be replaced with `System.out.println(true);`.

Comment: Have you tried pen and paper to see when the different branches will be picked? You have at least one too many.

Comment: The logic make little sense .

Comment: Ignoring the illogical logic, and extra elses... Is it possible that you're looking for a simple switch statement? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: I'm very confused.  Can you describe what you want this code to do?  What should it print out as written?  If x = 28 and y = 15, what should it print out?  If x = 15 and y = 15, what should it print out?

Comment: @JonathanSpiller Not sure how you'd make that into a `switch` statement though unless there's some enum somewhere that has results of comparisons (like `GREATER`, `LESS`, `EQUAL`).

Comment: This question is better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is just example of what you want to do. If not, the code can be replaced by `System.out.println(true);` as rgettman mentioned.

The last else can of course never get executed, since numbers are equal, or one is bigger, so it can be removed:

```
if (x == y) {
    System.out.println("They are equal");
} else if (x > y) {
    System.out.println("x is greater");
} else {
    System.out.println("x is smaller");
}
```

An alternative to the if-then statements is:

```
switch (Integer.compare(x, y))
{
   case -1: System.out.println("x is smaller"); break;
   case 0: System.out.println("They are equal"); break;
   default: System.out.println("x is greater"); // case 1
}
```

`Integer.compare` is Java 7 and up, before that you'll have to use `Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(y)`

Answer (score 2):

The output is always `true` as `||` with `true` always results `true`.

remove this line :

```
boolean state = (true || false);
```

Change it to:

```
  boolean state = (x==y);
    System.out.println(state);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what the comments are saying: In your `if/else` sequence, each conditional has the same execution block. Since the same output is achieved through several inputs (any of them being true would cause the output), you can condense this:

```
if (x == y) {
    System.out.println(state);
} else if (x > y) {
    System.out.println(state);
} else if (x < y) {
    System.out.println(state);
} else {
    System.out.println(state);
}
```

into this:

```
if(x == y || x > y || x < y){
    System.out.println(state);
} else { 
    System.out.println(state);
}
```

Two notes here. First, the boolean expression `x == y || x > y || x < y` (for numeric types, like `byte`, and assuming the variables are defined), includes *all* possibilities-- `x` *must* be either equal to, greater than, or less than `y`. That means that `x == y || x > y || x < y` is *always* true, so there is no point to the `else` block.

The second note is that in general, when you have something like this, where the two execution blocks are the same code:

```
if(expression){
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomething();
}
```

The `doSomething();` code will *always* be executed, no matter what, so having the conditionals is not necessary and can simply call the code and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give much details on the logics around `state`.

Another way to write your program is to have a `Map<Integer, Output>`, do `Byte.compareTo(anotherByte)` and lookup in the Map to get your desired Output.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted:

```
boolean b = (true || false);
```

will always set `b` to `true`.  I believe that this is what you're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
public static boolean compBytes(byte x, byte y)
{
    return (x.compareTo(y) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

But this will only work if you want `<` and `==` to both return false.  I think what you really want is:

```
public static int compBytes(byte x, byte y)
{
    return x.compareTo(y);
}
```

Then you can use a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to handle the cases.